# Firefox doesn't recognise media queries

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries, freemarker

I have a small template written in `FreeMarker` template language. I have the following piece of css in it:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
    @page {
        size: landscape;
    }
}
@media screen {
    .run {
        min-height: 100%;
    }
}
/* More css properties goes here */
</style>
```

The issue is that these two rules apply only when I'm opening web-page in Google Chrome. When I open it in Firefox, the `min-height` property doesn't apply to `.run` div, and Firefox prints my page in portrait mode, not in landscape as it was specified. What am I doing wrong?
P.S.: The doctype string, in case if it matters, looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know from when I worked in print styles that there are several rules that are used by some browsers and not by others.  I"m pretty sure size: landscape is one of them.  There are others like pagebreak that are used by Firefox and not by others.  So it's really hit and miss.  I wish you luck on your endeavor, working in HTML emails and print CSS are two things I loathe about working with the web.